# Was bedeutet "Puff" in Schweizer Deutsch?

Tags: dialect, swiss-standard-german

Ich bin gerade auf bei Blick.ch auf die Überschrift ["Schluss mit Zeiten-Puff"](http://www.blick.ch/news/wirtschaft/schluss-mit-zeiten-puff-191440) gestoßen.

Wird das in der Schweiz ohne Assoziationen an Bordell gebraucht, oder wird hier bewusst für eine große Unordnung diese Assoziation ausgenutzt?

Besteht die Assoziation in der Schweiz überhaupt?

Kann ein Schweizer Schüler diesen Begriff im Sinne des Artikels in einem Aufsatz verwenden ohne dass ihm das als Fehler angerechnet wird?

Comment: Entweder es ist ein Standarddeutsch ODER ein Dialekt. Bundesdeutsch ist eine Variante und nicht die absolute Wahrheit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wenn die Schweizer sagen, jemand *habe einen Puff*, meinen sie, dass nicht aufgeräumt wurde und Unordnung herrscht.

Was die Etymologie betrifft, so steht im [Blogbeitrag der Blogwiese "Haben Sie auch einen Puff daheim? — Die französischen Lehnwörter in der Schweiz](http://www.blogwiese.ch/archives/70)" *(Hervorhebung von mir):*

> Wie kommt es dazu? Nun, wie so oft, ist es ein **Lehnwort aus dem Französischen**. In Frankreich und somit auch in der Westschweiz sagt man “quel bordel“, wenn eine Situation besonders unübersichtlich oder verwirrend anmutet. Das wurde von den Schweizern irgendwann clever übersetzt.

Der Begriff *Puff* wird übrigens auch im Südtiroler Dialekt für Unordnung oder Chaos verwendet. Auch im Italienischen gibt es den umgangssprachlichen Begriff *bordello* ("che bordello!"), dessen Hauptbedeutung *Freudenhaus* ist.

Comment: man kann es auch Buff schreiben, oder?

Answer (score 4):

Im Schweizerdeutschen unterscheidet man zwischen:

*"Ich han es Puff"* = "Ich habe Unordnung/Durcheinander/Chaos."

und

*"Ich gange in Puff.", "Ich bin imene Puff gsii"* = "Ich gehe in ein Bordell", "Ich war in einem Bordell"

Das Wort 'Puff' im Sinne von Chaos hört man in der Schweiz im Alltag regelmässig. Es bedeutet nichts Anstössiges, selbst kleine Kinder im Kindergarten verwenden es (wobei ich mir denken kann, dass ursprünglich das eine vom anderen abgeleitet wurde).

Answer (score 2):

Nicht nur in der Schweiz, sondern auch in Deutschland hat **Puff** durchaus auch eine andere als die vermutete Bedeutung.

> **Puff** m. *Stoß, Schlag, dumpfer Schall*.<sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Puff&view=1)</sup>

Als *"Puff"* wird auch [Wurfzabel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wurfzabel), ein Backgammon-Vorläufer, bezeichnet.

[image]

<sub>**Anmerkung**: die im Wikipedia-Artikel getroffene Aussage, dass der Vulgärausdruck *"Puff"* (für Freudenhaus) seine Wurzel im Puff-Spiel hat, ist mehr als fraglich. Eher haben beide eine  gemeinsame Wortwurzel.</sub>

*Puff* findet sich auch häufig in zusammengesetzen Wörtern (z.B. *Auspuff*, *Puffärmel*, *Puffer*, *puffen*).

Darüber, ob auch der schweizerdeutsche Ausdruck *Puff* für [Unordnung](http://leben-schweiz.de/schweizerdeutsch-schwyzerdutsch/) eine gleiche etymologische Wurzel hat, habe ich nichts finden können.

Comment: Woher kommt Deine Skepsis? Ich kenne die Abstammung des vulgären Puffs nämlich nur so.

Comment: Ich hatte so ein Puffspiel, neu aus Pappe, aber mit nachgemachtem, historischem Aufdruck, und da waren dralle, nackte Frauen abgebildet. Ich nehme das als Hinweis, dass der Zusammenhang ehemals offensichtlicher war.

Answer (score 2):

Was die Verwendung des Wortes "Puff" betrifft, hat Splattne den Nagel auf den Kopf getroffen.

> Kann ein Schweizer Schüler diesen Begriff im Sinne des Artikels in einem Aufsatz verwenden ohne dass ihm das als Fehler angerechnet wird?

Wenn ein Schüler in der Schweiz in seinem Aufsatz schweizerdeutsche Wörter benutzt, wird dies in der Regel als Fehler gewertet.
Meist mit dem Vermerk, dass ein Begriff Mundart und nicht Schriftsprache ist.

Denn Grundsätzlich will man den Schülern korrekte Schriftsprache beibringen.

Es mag natürlich aus Ausnahmen geben, z.B. in Dialogen, bei denen der Dialekt des Charakters hervorgehoben wird.
Dies kann aber durchaus von Lehrer zu Lehrer variieren...

Ausserdem ist es so, dass in den ersten Schuljahren natürlich noch nicht auf solche Details geachtet wird.

Comment: +1 für die Beantwortung des Teilaspektes Gebrauch in Schulen. Leider ist meine Hauptfrage nach der Bedeutung, aber es impliziert jetzt die nächste Frage, was nämlich korrekte Schweizer Schriftsprache ist.

Comment: @berd_k Wenn man in der Schweiz von Schriftsprache spricht ist damit Standarddeutsch gemeint.

Comment: mit ß ? Ich dachte diesen überflüssigen Buchstaben hättet ihr nicht.

Comment: Nein, den haben wir nicht, aber ansonsten gibt es nicht viele Unterschiede.

Comment: @bernd_k Ich muss meine Aussage revidieren: Schriftsprache in der Schweiz ist nicht gleich Standdarddeutsch.
Ich dachte immer, ihr sprecht (bzw. schreibt) gleich wie wir. ;)