# Was ist korrekte Schweizer Schriftsprache?

Tags: swiss-standard-german, swiss-german

In seiner [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/3504/104) weist Lukas darauf hin, dass offenbar viele mundartliche Ausdrücke in der Schule als Fehler korrigiert werden.

Wie definiert sich denn nun die korrekte Schriftsprache ?

Answer (score 5):

Ich nehme an, dass in Deutschland Schriftsprache und Standarddeutsch ein und dasselbe sind.
Also, dass man nach Duden geht.

---

Bezüglich Österreich kann ich keine qualifizierte Aussage machen, nehme aber an, dass die Situation ähnlich ist wie in der Schweiz:
Es gibt eine Schriftsprache (formelles Deutsch), das nicht identisch mit dem deutschen Standarddeutsch ist.

---

In der Schweiz unterscheidet man Mundart (Dialekt) von der Schriftsprache.
Die Schriftsprache wird allgemein auch als Hochdeutsch bezeichnet, ist aber nicht identisch mit der deutschen Standardsprache.

Ausserdem ist das Schweizer Hochdeutsch nicht mit Schweizerdeutsch (Mundart) zu verwechseln.

---

Die Unterschiede liegen vor allem im Wortschatz und der Schreibweise.

So kennt man in der Schweiz beispielsweise das Zeichen **ß** nicht.
Anstelle dessen kommen zwei **s** zum Einsatz.

Standarddeutsch:

> massen, maßen

schweizer Hochdeutsch

> massen, massen

---

Betreffen dem Wortschatz gibt es viele Leihworte aus dem Französischen, welche man in der deutschen Standardsprache nicht antrifft:

> Perron – Bahnsteig
>
> Coiffeur – Frisör
>
> Trottoir – Gehsteig

Ausserdem gibt es Begriffe, die im Schweizer Hochdeutsch eine andere Bedeutung haben als im deutschen Standarddeutsch.

> Führerausweis – Führerschein
>
> Estrich – Dachboden
>
> parkieren – parken

Diese Begriffe sind keine dialektalen Ausdrücke, sondern korrekte "hochdeutsche" Ausdrücke.

Dialektale Ausdrücke (wie z. B. das "Puff" (Unordnung) in meiner [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3471/was-bedeutet-puff-in-schweizer-deutsch/3504#3504)) gelten in der Schweizer Schriftsprache als Stilfehler.

---

Gesprochen wird das Schweizer "Hochdeutsch" nur in formellem, öffentlichem Rahmen, wie beispielsweise den Nachrichten im Fernsehen, Schulen oder dem Parlament.
Ausserdem bei Anlässen, mit Teilnehmern, die den Dialekt nicht verstehen.

---

Einen sehr ausführlichen Artikel zur Schweizer Schriftsprache findet man auch auf [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweizer_Hochdeutsch).

Comment: In Österreich wird meinst das Österreichische Wörterbuch als Referenz verwendet: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Österreichisches_Wörterbuch